# Can I send all upload traffic through one specific network interface?

Tags: networking, server, 20.04

I have a server with 2 NICs running Ubuntu 20.04, how can I use one network interface for normal use, but configure the second interface for upload only?

For example, I wanted to upload my Database Backup files through my second NIC (which would be connected to another router - another network) to my cloud storage.

Can I do this? If so, how?